# Cannot disable phantom breakpoints in Firefox

Tags: debugging, firefox, breakpoints

Browser: Firefox 79 on Mac OSX Catalina

The Firefox debugger pauses JavaScript execution where there is no breakpoint set.  This renders the debugger useless as I'm unable to quickly get to the code of interest further downstream.  Is there a way to disable these phantom breakpoints?  Note: I'm not putting any debugger statements in my code.  This is vanilla JS code.

Screenshot... (notice no breakpoints set and message "Paused on breakpoint" in yellow.)

[image]

Comment: I'm working from memory here, but these things really frustrate me. On the breakpoints on the right side of your image, I think you can click on it when when throws, right-click and there is an option to remove breakpoint...or remove all breakpoints. This should clear it. There is a bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1553210. Some people refer to these as "pending" breakpoints: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1658546